# Find Most 40 liked pictures facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I Have to retrieve most 40 liked pictures with Facebook Grpah API.

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?access_token=' . $token);
$img_a = array();
foreach($albums['data'] as $keyalb => $valalb){
    $allimg = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$albums['data'][$keyalb]['id'].'/photos?limit=500&fields=source,like&access_token='.$token);
}
```

I am trying by this way but number of request is very high i can't use batch request because of pagination.

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible currently (without FQL) is to collect all photo data then post process checking the likes field.

Consider doing small requests to determine the "count" within each Album then use the count to balance out your batch request.